# How do I use Google Recaptcha v3 on page load without a form using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I'm trying to implement Google Recaptcha v3 on a particular page on my site. The content of the page is generated using PHP however I want to start filtering out some bot traffic. All examples that I'm finding online or SO are Form based examples, not page load examples.

I understand that Recaptcha can be used upon submitting an HTML form, but how does one use the API to determine if certain content on the page should be rendered or not via my backend (in PHP)?

I understand the initial Javascript part where I load the API and make a call to get a token, as follows:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=your reCAPTCHA site key here"></script>
    <script>
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        // do request for recaptcha token
        // response is promise with passed token
            grecaptcha.execute('your reCAPTCHA site key here', {action:'validate_captcha'})
                      .then(function(token) {
                // add token value to form
                document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value = token;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

It's beyond this that I am not sure what to do? Please provide code examples of how to implement using PHP.

Edit:

The content of my page is generated server-side using a call to a PHP function. I either want to
A) Protect this call to the PHP function from loading the content if the score meets certain threshold or as alternative
B) Stop my Google Ads from loading on the page if the score meets a certain threshold.

Comment: Is it an AJAX request you want to protect? You don't necessarily need to do anything at all in PHP... https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#programmatically_invoke_the_challenge . That could be used to stop the request from taking place, if it seems like the page has been loaded by a bot.

Comment: But if that's not your scenario, then you need to clarify a bit more exactly what's happening.

Comment: No, I'm not using AJAX to load the content. The content is generated server-side using a call to a PHP function. I either A) Want to protect that content from being loaded in PHP or B) Want to stop Google Ads (javascript snippet) from loading if the score is below 0.5 for example. I will update the question.

Comment: Ok. So let me get this straight. Basically you have a standard PHP page like "example.php". And normally you just put `https://www.example.com/example.php` into the browser, which generates a GET request to the server, and it shows the whole page content immediately. is that right? And now you're saying that some (unspecified) bots are loading this page automatically? a) how exactly have you detected that this is happening, and b) how do you imagine that recatpcha can solve it? Bots don't generally load your page into a browser, they just request the raw HTML programatically...

Comment: ...therefore (unless they are actually automating a browser by proxy) it's unlikely that any Javascript will be executed by the bot. And also even it did, by the time the time the Javascript is running, your page has already been loaded, and so the bot has already succeeded in executing your PHP, loading your page and consuming your resources. P.S. I'm not quite sure how the ads thing is relevant, since you've just added that detail to the question? Is the real issue here that you think ads are being served to bots? Again how have you detected that this is actually occurring?

Comment: The only things you can protect with recaptcha are a) specific javascript actions within an already-loaded page (as described at https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3), or b) form submissions where recaptcha can send a value indicating that it believes the form data was submitted by a human being. A bot cannot replicate that data. Recaptcha cannot protect general requests like just loading a page from scratch. There are no doubt other strategies you can use though, if you believe bots are doing that kind of thing - there are probably whole books written about the techniques, in fact.